# MS SQL: How to select from 2 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables -- one has `ProductID`, `[Product Name in English]` and `Price`. The other table has `ProductID` and `[Product Name in Spanish]`.

I want a select query that gives me the Product Name in Spanish and Price.

How do I do this using MS SQL?

In terms of database design, might I as well just put everything in one table and make the select query simpler? `ProductID`, `NameEnglish`, `NameSpanish`, `Price` for example.

Comment: No, do not combine them into the same table. what happens when you also want descriptions and other stuff in other languages, possibly more than just spanish? What about regional date formats and currency? Check into designing databases for locales if you're going in a direction of multi-lingual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.[Product Name in Spanish], t1.Price
    FROM table1 t1 -- The English version
        INNER JOIN table2 t2 -- The Spanish version
            ON t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID
```

As for your design question, think about future expansion. Will you ever want to store the name in another language like French? You may ultimately want to introduce a table of languages and a cross-reference table linking product and language. Something like:

[image]

Comment: With this setup, you dont need the field "EnglishName" since it will be included in the field translation for the english language id. But it is the right solution. Could also make a view to make the tables act like 1 table for select purposes.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: Granted, it's a bit of a denormalization, but I like to keep the English (or whatever your native language may be) description with the product just to give some meaning to the rows of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Combining them would be the best solution, but using a JOIN will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the JOIN operator:

```
SELECT
  tab2.[Product name in Spanish],
  tab1.Price
FROM
  table1 tab1
INNER JOIN
  table2 tab2 on tab2.ProductID=tab1.ProductID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an inner join, but I don't see any reason to have two separate tables, I would combine them personally.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SP.ProductName, PRODUCT.Price from PRODUCT as PRODUCT 
   JOIN SPANISHPRODUCTS as SP ON PRODUCT.ProductID = SP.ProductID
```